# why I can't apply new CSS to my project while it worked fine at the beginning?

Tags: php, html, css

At the begining I worked on the design of my website and I finished it.

then I wanted to add the PHP part so I changed the structure of the files and altered html extensions into php, then I checked every thing up and it worked just fine.

But when I came to add some changes to the css file it won't apply new changes.

So I copied the code into another file with html extensions and it's being applying new changes normally.

That's why I stuck with this technic for a while but after that none of the both ways worked for me even the file with html extensions won't apply new CCS changes . And now I am comfused and don't want to start over.

If you you ever went through something like this and found your way around please let me know.

Comment: What do you mean with "it won't work"? If you meant new styles don't apply even after you refresh the browser then: remember that the browser caches CSS files and that you can open an incognito tab (which does not use anything cached before it was opened), or clear browser cache.

Answer (score 1):

So you have changed .html files to .php extension. If you are using css in external file you don't need to change the extension for css file, keep it as .css only. If the external css is not working, try giving internal css using style attribute in  or inline css if comfortable.
If it still does not work try using ob_start() in php.
You can try clearing the cache from the browser as sometimes cache from browser resists css styles.

```
header("Cache-Control: no cache");
session_cache_limiter("private_no_expire");
```

Above code might help you to clear cache and session cache from the webpage in php.